# Find the sum of all numbers entered

Tags: c, sum

I need to read the number inputs from the user until they type in 0, print the sum of all entered number.

I am hoping to get this response:

```
Enter n: 50 
Enter n: 25  
Enter n: 10 
Enter n: 0  
total=85
```

So far my code is (sorry for my variables):

```
char ya;
float tem, ye, sum, roun=0.0;


printf("Enter n: ");
scanf("%f" ,&ye);

while (ye > 0 || tem > 0)
{
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%f", &tem);
    roun = roun + tem;
}
sum = sum + ye;
printf("Total= %f\n", sum);
```

Comment: `roun = roun + tem` Seems like `roun` is the sum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code you have shared. First of all for the code you have provided, you need to ensure temp is also initialised to 0. i.e temp=0

Then you already have some value in ye means the loop will not terminate. You once you are inside while loop, you need to reset the value of ye to 0. But before that you need to include the value of ye in the sum. So you will have to sum = sum + ye before the while loop.

Also in your code, you need to add round to sum and not ye.
So if I was to correct your code, it will look like below

```
tem=0;
printf("Enter n: ");
scanf("%f" ,&ye);
roun=ye;
while (ye > 0 || tem > 0)
{
    printf("Enter n: ");
    scanf("%f", &tem);
    roun = roun + tem;
    ye=0;
}
sum = sum + roun;
printf("Total= %f\n", sum);
```

but a better approach is to use do-while loops rather and have a code like below

```
do
{
  printf("Enter n: ");
     scanf("%f", &tem);
     sum = sum + tem;  
} while(tem>0);
printf("Total= %f\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
roun = roun + tem;
```

You add the values to `roun`, not `sum`. So `noun` should be the final value.

Then,

```
sum = sum + ye;
```

does not make sense. Because `sum` is uninitialized and it's value in indeterminate.

Aside: You can write `sum += ye;` instead of `sum = sum + ye;`.